# Android TextView not aligning below ImageView

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview

```
<TextView android:text="ABC" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The code below should align text to bottom right corner below the image. But that's not happening

```
<TextView
    android:text="XYZ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pic"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/androidparty"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pic"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Android TextView not aligning below ImageView

`TextView` not aligning below of `ImageView` due to `alignParentBottom` attribute set to `true` for TextView.

Remove `alignParentBottom` attribute from TextView :

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:layout_below="@id/pic" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Comment: @MuditKakkar: Yes right using `alignParentBottom` attribute view  aligned according to parent instead of other view

Comment: The text is not visible anywhere on the screen. Suggestions?